# Put a boundary line on the image that is already clipped to shapefile, the boundary of the same shapefile in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, image, boundaries, plot

I managed to clip the image to the shapefile, but when I plot I see that it is following the pattern of the shapefile, but I want the boundary to appear on the final image too.

Here is the code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= (10,8))


shpNDVI2014 .plot.imshow(ax=ax, cmap = 'rainbow') ----- DATA IMAGE

shapefile.plot(ax=ax, color = 'white', alpha= 0, facecolor = 'k')------- SHAPEFILE IMAGE

plt.ylabel('Latitude', fontsize =12)
plt.xlabel('Longitude', fontsize =12)
plt.title('NDVI2014')
plt.show()
```